# communication between GAE and GKE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, vpc

I need some help about communication between GAE and GKE.
I have :
 - a golang application deployed on GAE region europe-west2.
 - a Elasticsearch cluster on GKE region europe-west1-d.
The GKE service has annotations:
cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: Internal.

I would like to connect both. How do ? In fact that a GAE microservice able to request ES.
I create 2 VPC network and appair them.
Using flex GAE for specify network and sub.
What's wrong ? It's not possible ?

Comment: You question is not clear enough. You said GAE can sent request ot ES? So what's your real problem? What error message did you got?

Comment: I suppose that the problem comes from network configuration.
When I deploy GAE flex app, that fail cause the ES seems not accessible.
The error is app error, I dont know if that can help for solution. But this is the log : 
time="2019-03-16T15:34:21Z" level=panic msg="Head http://10.51.249.171:9200: context deadline exceeded"
I found really less documentation about communication between GAE and GKE. Maybe because normaly there is not problem. I don't know shame, I'm not network specialist... so

Answer (score 0):

The internal load balancer you are using to expose the GKE service can only be accessed within the same region and network (peered network and VPNs are fine).
GAE normally does not get deployed within a network in your project.

However, based on your comment, it seems you are using App Engine Flex. Make sure the GAE Flex instance is created in the same region as your GKE cluster and that they are either in the same network or are using Peered networks.